# Does Tor Browser allow non-Tor content (http/https) on .onion sites?

Tags: security

Does Tor Browser allow non-Tor content (http/https) on .onion sites?

Suppose I visit somesite.onion and it has .css or .js or image with source from usual http/https site. Will it load it? Or visiting .onion site it allows only .onion content?

Answer (score 2):

An `*.onion` site can embed for example an image from a clearweb site `*.com`.

You can use Tor Browser to surf normal clearweb sites like CNN.com